# Does this impact if I delete old rev of SDK Built Tools?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have some apps running api 19 does this impact if I just delete these old SDK built tools? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Apps are running on Rev. 19, you could delete everything below 19.
The question is - why would you want to delete them?
If you delete them and something stops working, you can just reinstall what you need via SDK Manager.